# Unexpected database output when using INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
       r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID,
       ra.BEZEICHNUNG AS raumBEZEICHNUNG, ra.ID AS raumID
FROM 
       RAUM r
       INNER JOIN RAZUORDNUNG rz ON rz.RAUM_ID = r.ID
       INNER JOIN RAUMATTRIBUTE ra ON rz.RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID = ra.ID 

WHERE
       RAUMKLASSE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumklasse_ID, RAUMKLASSE_ID) 
AND    STADT_ID = ISNULL(@Stadt_ID, STADT_ID) 
AND    GEBAEUDE_ID = ISNULL(@Gebaeude_ID, GEBAEUDE_ID) 
AND    REGION_ID = ISNULL(@Region_ID, REGION_ID)
AND    RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumattribute_ID, RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID)
```

But I think that something is wrong with that.

For example:

If I put `three` in the `RAUMKLASSE_ID` textfield in the browser and invoke my method it returns only one room. But there are six rooms with that ID. The strange thing is, that if I remove the two `INNER JOIN` and the second line of my `SELECT`, like this:

```
SELECT 
       r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID
FROM 
       RAUM r
WHERE
       RAUMKLASSE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumklasse_ID, RAUMKLASSE_ID) 
AND    STADT_ID = ISNULL(@Stadt_ID, STADT_ID) 
AND    GEBAEUDE_ID = ISNULL(@Gebaeude_ID, GEBAEUDE_ID) 
AND    REGION_ID = ISNULL(@Region_ID, REGION_ID)
AND    RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumattribute_ID, RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID)
```

it is returning the six rooms, which is correct. I don't know what the problem is with my query. Maybe someone can help me with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because only one of the 6 rooms has related data to the other two tables?

Comment: What happens if you turn the two `JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: same behaviour as with INNER JOIN

Comment: Please translate your code to english too when asking questions. Not everyone understands german, and this makes reading your code difficult.

Comment: In addition - unless you expect the result to be WRONG (i.e. an error that provides results that are technically wrong) this is the wrong question. It is more "Unxpected" result - due to bad SQL.

Comment: Are all the 5 parameters from the `Room` table?

Comment: No. RAUMKLASSE_ID, STADT_ID, GEBAEUDE_ID and REGION_ID are from the Room Table and the RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID is from the RAUMATTRIBUTE Table

Comment: Then your second query would give error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, since:

```
FROM RAUM r
INNER JOIN RAZUORDNUNG rz ON rz.RAUM_ID = r.ID
INNER JOIN RAUMATTRIBUTE ra ON rz.RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID = ra.ID
```

Will get you only the rooms that are found in the tables `RAUM`, `RAZUORDNUNG` and `RAUMATTRIBUTE` tables, removing these `INNER JOIN`s will get you all the rooms from the `RAUM` table that satisfy your condition, check these pages for more details about `JOIN`s:

- [A visual explanation for `JOIN`s](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).
- [Wikipedia article about `JOIN`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: Yes. It is "Unxpected" not "WRONG" result.

Comment: ah ok i understand the problem now. But how can i return also the Room which are not found in the RAZUORDNUNG and RAUMATTRIBUT Tables?

Comment: @Paks, In this case you should `LEFT JOIN` them with the `RAUM` table like this: `SELECT FROM RAUM r LEFT JOIN RAZUORDNUNG ...`

Comment: I may be wrong, but am still not satisfied; if you need all entries from your table RAUM, the LEFT JOIN would be the one to apply, to my knowledge. I would fear here that the RIGHT JOIN, though ok with your current data, is not what you need. Maybe you have to reformulate with a nested join, st like: SELECT ... FROM RAUM r LEFT JOIN ( RAZUORDNUNG rz INNER JOIN RAUMATTRIBUTE ON ...) ON rz.RAUM_ID = r.ID WHERE ...?

Answer (score 2):

INNER JOIN won't return RAUM entries that have no corresponding RAZUORDNUNG or RAUMATTRIBUTE. You may need a LEFT JOIN instead; in this case, raumBEZEICHNUNG and raumID may be null in the returned set.

Comment: i tried a LEFT JOIN instead, but it has the same behaviour as INNER JOIN