# how to set the sql output unique?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected database output when using INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114987/unexpected-database-output-when-using-inner-join)

hello i have a sql query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID, ra.BEZEICHNUNG AS raumBEZEICHNUNG, ra.ID AS raumID 
FROM RAZUORDNUNG rz 
right join RAUMATTRIBUTE ra ON rz.RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID = ra.ID 
right join RAUM r ON rz.RAUM_ID = r.ID
WHERE ....
```

i write the results in a list:

```
strasseObject.Add(new RAUM()
                      {
                          RaumName = rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"].ToString(),
                          RaumID = rdr["ID"].ToString(),
                          RaumAttribute = rdr["raumBEZEICHNUNG"].ToString(),
                          RaumAttributeID = rdr["raumID"].ToString()
                      });
```

and the output look like this

```
<RAUM>
<RaumName>Small Business Room</RaumName>
<RaumID>219</RaumID>
<RaumAttribute>A7OVERHEAD</RaumAttribute>
<RaumAttributeID>168876</RaumAttributeID>
</RAUM>
<RAUM>
<RaumName>Small Business Room</RaumName>
<RaumID>219</RaumID>
<RaumAttribute>Beamer</RaumAttribute>
<RaumAttributeID>168847</RaumAttributeID>
</RAUM>
</ArrayOfRAUM>
```

you can see that i get 2 results with the same "RaumName" but with different "Raumattribute". i want an output like this:

```
<RAUM>
<RaumName>Small Business Room</RaumName>
<RaumID>219</RaumID>
<RaumAttribute>A7OVERHEAD</RaumAttribute>
<RaumAttributeID>168876</RaumAttributeID>
<RaumAttribute>Beamer</RaumAttribute>
<RaumAttributeID>168847</RaumAttributeID>
</RAUM>
</ArrayOfRAUM>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to do with the multiple RaumAttributes? Not shown at all (Just remove them from your select list), shown as a list under the same RaumName, or what?

Comment: There are a few options, but the simplest is to make one search to gather all your RaumName objects, add them to a list. Then another search for each of those objects which finds the attributes associated with it. Or using DataTables, relationships, etc.

Comment: You sould add a GROUP BY in the SQL...

Comment: That won't help at all @JorgeFerreira .

Comment: i just deleted the raumattribute in my select statement. i don't need it. it works now. anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, i didnt understand at first. When you run the SQL directly do you notice that there are double rows? Also, can you have/do you really want to have multiple nodes with the same name? i dont think that is going to work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start the query on the other end (select from raum)?

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID, ra.BEZEICHNUNG AS raumBEZEICHNUNG, ra.ID AS raumID
FROM RAUM r
right join RAZUORDNUNG rz ON rz.RAUM_ID = r.ID
right join RAUMATTRIBUTE ra ON rz.RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID = ra.ID
WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `rz.RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID` column from your query, and than run.... like

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID, ra.BEZEICHNUNG AS raumBEZEICHNUNG, ra.ID AS raumID 
FROM RAZUORDNUNG rz 
right join RAUMATTRIBUTE ra ON rz.RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID = ra.ID 
right join RAUM r ON rz.RAUM_ID = r.ID
WHERE ....
```

**Distinct:** The `DISTINCT` keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values. So, RAUMATTRIBUTE_ID has different values that's why it return 2 rows.